# Drop value if is too different from the previous and following - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-munging

I want to drop values from a dataframe when is too different from the previous or the following one.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Watt':[554, 557, 51, 480, 601, 458, 19, 492, 503, 22, 399]})
```

For example here I need to drop (51, 19, 22), kind of "outliers".

I want to drop not with a condition like `< x` but considering a variation in percentage with the previous and the following values.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, why 492 should be dropped? Doesn't look like outlier.

Comment: It's a mistake. Tanks

Answer (score 0):

The following will lead to the desired output:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Watt':[554, 557, 51, 480, 601, 458, 19, 492, 503, 22, 399]})
df['previous percent'] = df.Watt/df.Watt.shift(1)
df['next percent'] = df.Watt.shift(-1)/df.Watt

threshold_previous = .8
threshold_next = 2

df[(1-df['previous percent'] < threshold_previous) & 
   (df['next percent']-1 < threshold_next)]
```

A slightly more elegant solution would be:

```py
df['average'] = (df.Watt.shift(1) + df.Watt.shift(-1)) / 2
threshold = .8
df[df.Watt/df.average > threshold]
```

But it depends on your use case.